# Need to clarify what 'reverse (data, data+n)' does in this code

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

```
 void bckuetsrot(int data[], int n)
 {
    int x = 65537;
    int bckuet[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        buckets[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        bckuet[data[i]]++;
        q++;
    }
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < x; j++)
     {
         for (int k = bckuet[j]; k > 0; k--)
         {
              data[i++] = j;
              q++;
         }
     }

    reverse(data, data + n);
 }
```

What does `reverse(data, data+n);` do? Does it reverse the **algorithm** of the code or the **output** of the program? Or it has other meaning/definition?

I need some clarification. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I assume `using namespace std;` is somewhere in that code, if so, check http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/

Comment: When dealing with large amounts of data like this, you should allocate it on the heap, or you might run into stack overflows.

Answer (score 0):

Reverses the order of the elements in the range (first,last)

Bidirectional iterators to the initial and final positions of the sequence to be reversed. The range used is [first,last), which contains all the elements between first and last, including the element pointed by first but not the element pointed by last.